# elasticsearch index in production profile in jhipster

Tags: jhipster

I have configured my application-prod.yml with the installed elasticsearch's elasticsearch.yml.
 when we run *mvn -Pprod* (running the jhipster app in prod profile),app is running without error. But I don't know where is the elasticsearch index created.
When I search in browser localhost:1000/_cat/indices?v it doesn't show anything as there is no index present. But when I'm creating a row in entity it is created and after searching the same index it shows result.In my node it is not present.

I want to know in prod profile how the elastisearch index is created and stored.
here is changes done by me in application-prod.yml for elasticsearch.

file:application-prod.yml

```
data:
        elasticsearch:
            cluster-name:my-application
            cluster-nodes:localhost:1000
```

file:elasticsearch.yml

```
cluster.name: my-application
node.name: mynode
path.data: W:\Apurva\ElasticSearch\elasticsearch-5.1.2\data
path.logs: W:\Apurva\ElasticSearch\elasticsearch-5.1.2\logs
http.port: 1000
```